# I have 2 json objects in python,For each of the sections in the 2nd object i need to append and nest them into the first. How would i acheive this?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

Apologies if this does not make sense but i have explained it the best i can.

I have 2 json objects in python **(orderdetails,orderlines)** with a common field **(order_id)**

For each of the **{data between the brackets with the same order_id as orderdetails}** in orderlines i need to append and nest them into order details so the end result looks like this:
[End Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWcZz.png)

orderdetails is the large data and the orderlines is the small data.

My data is pulled from SQL and then transformed subsequently to a dataframe and then json.

I've looked at a few questions on this but must of them don't really relate to what i want to do.

Here is the below  code i currently have:

```
from func.excelfunction import *
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
import requests
import csv
import os
import math
from sql_server.sql_server import *
import pandas as pd
import json

#variables 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


df1 = run_sql_df('SET NOCOUNT ON; exec isawitfirstdb.dbo.usp_Torque_orderDetails')
df1 = df1.astype({"created_at":"str","order_number":"str","order_id":"int64","instructions":"str","dispatch_method":"str","email":"str","Contact":"str",
"name":"str","address_1":"str","address_2":"str","town":"str","county":"str","postcode":"str","country":"str","invoice_currency":"str",
"subtotal_price":"str","total_price":"str","invoice_name":"str","invoice_contact_phone":"str","invoice_address_1":"str","invoice_address_2":"str",
"invoice_town":"str","invoice_county":"str","invoice_postcode":"str","inovice_country":"str","Owner_id":"str","Merge_status":"str","Merge_action":"str","Record_type":"str"})

df2 = run_sql_df('SET NOCOUNT ON; exec isawitfirstdb.dbo.usp_Torque_orderLineDetails')
df2 = df2.astype({"sku_id":"str","order_id":"int64","qty_ordered":"int64","user_def_type_1":"str","user_def_type_2":"str","user_def_num_1":"str","line_value":"int64","config_id":"str","Merge_status":"str","Merge_action":"str","Record_type":"str"})

#convert to dataframe
orders = pd.DataFrame(df1)
orderlines = pd.DataFrame(df2)

#convert to dataframe to json
orders = orders.to_json(orient="records")
orderlines = orderlines.to_json(orient="records")

# JSON
df = orders + orderlines

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `some_dict.update({'some_exclusive_key': some_object})` to append to a dict

Answer (score 0):

I assume only one record exists for each `order_id` in `orders` but multiple can exist in `orderlines`. If so, you can iterate through the list of orders and, for each record, append a new field with the list of `orderlines` that match that `order_id`. You can get that list using `filter()`

```py
new_list = []
for rec in orders:
    order_id = rec.get('order_id')
    matching_orderlines = list(filter(lambda ol: ol['order_id'] == order_id, orderlines))
    new_list.append({*rec,'lines':matching_orderlines})
```

I am also assuming that the key `order_id` always exists. if not, replace brackets by `.get()`. I din't test the code above...